# Chart JS stacked labels instead of making them horizontal

Tags: php, arrays, json, chart.js

Passing array object to labels of ChartJS. I am passing an array from PHP to ChartJS. The values are supposed to form the horizontal labels of the chart but it only displayed stacked on each other. How do I resolve it?

```
var answers = <?php echo json_encode($answerArray); ?>;
    var countList = <?php echo json_encode($countList); ?>;
    console.log(answers);

    var areaChartData = {
      labels  : [answers],
      datasets: [
        {
          label               : 'Digital Goods',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
          pointRadius         : false,
          pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
          pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
          data                : [50, 60, 70, 80 , 90]
        },
        {
          label               : 'Electronics',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointRadius         : false,
          pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data                : [50, 60, 70, 80 , 90]
        },
                {
          label               : 'Welath',
          backgroundColor     : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          borderColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointRadius         :  false,
          pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
          data                : [50, 60, 70, 80 , 90]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is the result I got on the chart:

[image: Chart stacked result]

This is how I expect it looks like:

[image: This is what I expected]

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour comes from that your labels array contains an array containing an array with all labels like this: `[["label1", "label2", "label3"]]` this is meant for multiline labels. You need to make sure your labels are in a single array like this: `["label1", "label2", "label3"]` then it will render correctly.

A simple fix for this is replace `labels: [answers],` by `labels: answers,`

Comment: You've really made my day! Thanks a lot.